# Is there a way to view one's iTunes Match content online?

Tags: itunes-match

After having removed a song from iTunes (and having selected "remove from iCloud") checkbox, my iPhone believes it still can downloaded from the iCloud.

I wonder, if it's possible to view one's content from the stand point of Apple. Do they have the song I removed or do they not? If they do, under my account, I'd like to be able to remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question. You removed a song from iTunes/iCloud and it still shows up on your iPhone? Looks like you just need a new resync with your iCloud. Or what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The clients that access the data are iTunes on the Mac and Windows OS as well as the music app on iOS.

I've seen some desktop iTunes libraries get messed up and not ask to delete a song from the cloud. In that case, set up a new user account on the same computer and sign in and try the delete again.

- [iTunes Store: How to delete songs from iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4915)